# how to test a vue 3 component with cypress (10.x) using v-model

Tags: vue.js, cypress, vuejs3

I've created a component using a v-model and I want to component test it, but I can't seem to make the v-model work with the mount(). Here's my test and a couple of things I've tried. Thx.

```js
import { mount } from 'cypress/vue'
import Component from '../../../src/components/MyComponent.vue'

let myData = null
let columns = null

beforeEach(() => {
    cy.fixture('MyFixture.json').then(function (data) {
        myData = data
    })
})

...
it('initial test', () => {
    mount(Component, {
        props: {
            value: myData,
        }
    })
})
```

I've also tried `'v-model': myData` but nothing seems to work.

Note that all other props works, they are omitted here for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer is modelValue

```js
it('initial test', () => {
    mount(Component, {
        props: {
            modelValue: myData,
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Logically we would also want to update the value of myData during the test to confirm the effect on the component, I tried this locally but the mounted cypress component does not take into account the change of a modelValue variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DMonkey: I had a similar question: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73895960/how-to-test-reactiveness-of-vue-component-in-cypress-componet-tests/73900285#73900285.

Comment: @DMonkey did you find out how to modify the value of myData and assess the effect on the component? I am also stuck with that I can not change the modelValue after the component was mounted

Comment: any update on this how to correctly test v model with cypress