# How to test reactiveness of Vue Component in Cypress Componet tests

Tags: unit-testing, cypress, vuejs3, cypress-component-test-runner

I am trying to test if a prop of a vue component is reactive using cypress component tests. Strangely it looks reactive, because my test is not even able to test if the original value was rendered as expected. Sadly it is not enough to test if the final value appears in the component, because in a RW the dependencies are so complicated, that I want to test chains of changes.

From my point of view it seems like cypress executes all the code of the test before the component is mounted and later waits on `cy.get(...).contains`, but nothing I did to delay this process (trying to wrap the change in a `within` statement, delaying it by `wait` or making the whole thing asynchronous) fixed the problem.

I cooked it down to the example given below.

This is my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1 data-cy="content">{{ content }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {computed} from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  object_prop: Object
})

const content = computed(() => {
  return String(props.object_prop.value);
})
</script>
```

This is the corresponding test:

```
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld.vue'

describe('<HelloWorld />', () => {
    it('renders', () => {
        let data = {value: "Hello"}
        cy.mount(HelloWorld, {props: {object_prop: data}});
        cy.get('[data-cy="content"]').contains("Hello");
        data.value = "Bye";
        cy.get('[data-cy="content"]').contains("Bye");
    })
})
```

This is the cypress screenshot:
[image]

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So how did you get "Bye" on the page if you were not using `component.setProps()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try with using `then`?

```js
describe('<HelloWorld />', () => {
    it('renders', () => {
        let data = {value: "Hello"}
        cy.mount(HelloWorld, {props: {object_prop: data}}).then((wrapper) => {
            component = wrapper;
        });
        cy.get('[data-cy="content"]').contains("Hello").should(() => {
            component.setProps({object_prop: {value: "Bye"}})
        })
        cy.get('[data-cy="content"]').contains("Bye");
    })
})
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then

`then` will allow making the change after the getter or assertion finishes, so it will help the change execute in the correct order

Comment: Thanks a lot. That might not work, but gave me the correct hint. As Daniel said one has to use `then` (or `should`) to stall the action. On top of that `data` is not the proxy seen as the prop, so I did fall back to use vue-test-utils `setProps` method to set the value.